# create service caused kubernetes error?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using kubernetes v1.9 with centos7

after i init the cluster, and create rc successfully, while i create service, the kubernetes would fail:

```html
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.5", GitCommit:"f01a2bf98249a4db383560443a59bed0c13575df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-19T15:59:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.6", GitCommit:"9f8ebd171479bec0ada837d7ee641dec2f8c6dd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-21T15:13:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

[root@localhost ~]# kubectl get rc

NAME      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE

mysql     1         1         1         39m

**BEFORE CREATE SERVICE, EVERYTHING IS OK, BUT WHILE I CREATE SERVICE:**

[root@localhost ~]# kubectl create -f ~/kuber/mysql-svc.yaml

Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

[root@localhost ~]# kubectl get rc

Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

[root@localhost ~]# kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.5", GitCommit:"f01a2bf98249a4db383560443a59bed0c13575df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-19T15:59:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
**Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout**
```

the yaml file is like this:

```html
# cat ~/kuber/mysql-svc.yaml

apiVersion: v1

kind: Service

metadata:

  name: mysql

spec:

  ports:

- port: 3306

  selector:

app: mysql
```

Can someone tell me that's why?

And how to create a service correctly?

---

the kubelet service is running, but there are some error information:

```html
# systemctl status kubelet -l
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since 二 2018-03-27 17:05:50 CST; 15h ago
     Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 10352 (kubelet)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           ├─10352 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true --network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --cluster-dns=10.96.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local --authorization-mode=Webhook --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cadvisor-port=0 --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --rotate-certificates=true --cert-dir=/var/lib/kubelet/pki
           └─36095 iptables -w -N KUBE-FIREWALL -t filter

3月 28 08:27:24 localhost.localdomain kubelet[10352]: E0328 08:27:24.160858   10352 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dlocalhost.localdomain&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:27:25 localhost.localdomain kubelet[10352]: E0328 08:27:25.220630   10352 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:471: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:27:25 localhost.localdomain kubelet[10352]: E0328 08:27:25.122992   10352 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:480: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dlocalhost.localdomain&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:27:26 localhost.localdomain kubelet[10352]: W0328 08:27:25.799971   10352 prober.go:103] No ref for container "docker://48f74ec3374213760ee72a18eee978105d5cb6737a5324020bee6b1b0d45eb79" (kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-w5rgq_kube-system(788acf83-3197-11e8-b0eb-000c2976ef29):kubedns)
3月 28 08:27:28 localhost.localdomain kubelet[10352]: W0328 08:27:27.560076   10352 status_manager.go:459] Failed to get status for pod "kube-controller-manager-localhost.localdomain_kube-system(cca3952635c33c6b1e1c42d54e3d7e18)": Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-controller-manager-localhost.localdomain: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:27:28 localhost.localdomain kubelet[10352]: E0328 08:27:27.785196   10352 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dlocalhost.localdomain&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:27:28 localhost.localdomain kubelet[10352]: E0328 08:27:28.930804   10352 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:471: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:27:29 localhost.localdomain kubelet[10352]: E0328 08:27:29.130705   10352 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:480: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dlocalhost.localdomain&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:27:30 localhost.localdomain kubelet[10352]: E0328 08:27:30.379361   10352 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dlocalhost.localdomain&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:27:30 localhost.localdomain kubelet[10352]: W0328 08:27:29.965228   10352 status_manager.go:459] Failed to get status for pod "kube-scheduler-localhost.localdomain_kube-system(0f95caae4a7fffab092dfa6db3c27347)": Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-scheduler-localhost.localdomain: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

---

restart kubelet seems useless:

```html
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status kubelet -l
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since 三 2018-03-28 08:32:03 CST; 1min 28s ago
     Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 36455 (kubelet)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─36455 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --allow-privileged=true --network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin --cluster-dns=10.96.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local --authorization-mode=Webhook --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cadvisor-port=0 --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --rotate-certificates=true --cert-dir=/var/lib/kubelet/pki

3月 28 08:33:30 localhost.localdomain kubelet[36455]: E0328 08:33:30.192129   36455 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:480: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dlocalhost.localdomain&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:33:30 localhost.localdomain kubelet[36455]: W0328 08:33:30.192360   36455 prober.go:103] No ref for container "docker://c72ddcf19c2ff80e00df0910da43a23600fe335412c8611a00260179c0f6a722" (kube-scheduler-localhost.localdomain_kube-system(0f95caae4a7fffab092dfa6db3c27347):kube-scheduler)
3月 28 08:33:30 localhost.localdomain kubelet[36455]: E0328 08:33:30.192377   36455 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dlocalhost.localdomain&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:33:31 localhost.localdomain kubelet[36455]: E0328 08:33:31.321350   36455 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:471: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:33:31 localhost.localdomain kubelet[36455]: E0328 08:33:31.342084   36455 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dlocalhost.localdomain&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:33:31 localhost.localdomain kubelet[36455]: E0328 08:33:31.342605   36455 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:480: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dlocalhost.localdomain&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:33:31 localhost.localdomain kubelet[36455]: I0328 08:33:31.761668   36455 kubelet_node_status.go:273] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
3月 28 08:33:32 localhost.localdomain kubelet[36455]: E0328 08:33:32.556183   36455 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dlocalhost.localdomain&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:33:32 localhost.localdomain kubelet[36455]: E0328 08:33:32.556318   36455 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:480: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dlocalhost.localdomain&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
3月 28 08:33:32 localhost.localdomain kubelet[36455]: E0328 08:33:32.556375   36455 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:471: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.88.129:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.88.129:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl get node        
The connection to the server 192.168.88.129:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Comment: Could you check if kubelet is still running? systemctl status kubelet

Comment: Could you restart all the kuberenetes services (once I saw in my new k8s cluster services were throwing crashLoopBackOff , after restart everything was running fine ), or if in production then can you check your kuberenetes logs or kubelet if its up or running? Maybe when you are requesting to create this service its killing one of the k8s services.

Comment: kubelet is running with error log, I restart kebelet service is useless, the log is too long and I edit and add then in my question, thanks!

Comment: kubectl isn't able to talk to the api server, so the service isn't getting installed. kubelet isn't able to talk to the api server either. something is wrong with your cluster.